# Why electronic band structure of any material wiggles in reciprocal space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, crystals, electronic-band-theory

I have a doubt regarding, why changing of position in brillouin zone changes the energy levels?
This is because there is a change in the wave functions at every point in brillouin zone. But why is wave function changes? Here, I have attached band structure of 'Si'. [image]

How can we identify the s, p, d, f orbitals by looking at the image? Under which condition it on crystal dimensions, it will nearly stop wiggling?
Please, clarify my doubts.Thanks!

Comment: The Brillouin zone labels the momentum of states - wouldn't it be weirder if the energy _didn't_ depend on momentum?

Comment: Your question about s, p, d, etc. orbitals is really separate from your main question an I believe is answered [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/278844/why-do-p-orbitals-correspond-to-the-valence-band-in-semiconductors/278999#278999)

Comment: You can't regard a crystal as a bunch of s, p, d, ... atomic orbitals. At a particular point in $k$ space you can answer the question of what the overlap of an atomic orbital with a the Bloch function is, but that answer really doesn't get you anywhere.